# How much water to add to rice cooker when cooking brown rice?

Tags: rice, rice-cooker

I usually use 1.5 cups of water for every cup of 'white basmati' rice.

Today I used 4 cups of water for 1 cup of 'brown basmati' rice and it came out a bit watery.  however i did add more of the water after one round of cooking so maybe that had something to do with the visible water in the rice cooker?

Comment: Where did you get a 1-4 ratio? Have you looked at your rice cooker's guide on this?

Comment: To add to Catija's comment, rice cookers usually have lines directly on the pot (something like [this](http://www.cookingideal.com/4573-thickbox_default/rice-cooker-warmer-replacement-inner-pot.jpg)) and if not I imagine the manual would have an explanation. Have you looked at those? Or are you intentionally ignoring them for brown rice?

Comment: Actually it doesn't specify anything for brown rice.  It says 1:1.5 for just rice. I got the 1:4 from a guide on the internet.

Comment: Was it for boiling and draining? I've never seen anything near that high even for brown rice.

Comment: no it was a guide on how much to add to a rice cooker when doing brown rice.  however it seems a lot of mentions online are saying less.  perhaps ill just have to do trial and error and work it out.  can we just say 1:2 rice to water ratio is enough?

Comment: Can you clarify please, you said you used a ratio of 4/1 water/rice, but that you 'did add more of the water after one round of cooking'. Do you mean that you added 4 cups of water to your one cup of rice, cooked it until all that was gone and added more water? or that you added 4 cups water in total, but did so in two stages?

Comment: You can certainly get rice cooker books that give the ratios for all sorts of rice, for typical rice cookers if a variety of sizes (as the surface area has an effect). This information appears to be available online as well. I've mostly seen 1:2 but also 1:2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little experimentation with each machine is in order as boiling time and amount of steam lost varies.

A good starting point for short-grain brown rice is to cover by inch.
2 inches if rice is to be rinsed and further steamed.

Answer (score 1):

Overall It depends on the machine/pot you're using. At work we determine it by comparing the amount of water that is above the rice but at home I do a 2:1 ratio, both come out about the same. You just need to figure out your machine and/or pot.